# Angular global trackBy property directive with strict type checking

Tags: angular, typescript

I want make a unique trackBy directive by passing a property name for track the ngFor item, this is the code:

```
import { NgForOf } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, Host, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngForTrackByProp]',
})
export class NgForTrackByPropDirective<T> {
  private propertyName: keyof T;

  constructor(@Host() public ngForOf: NgForOf<T>) {
    this.ngForOf.ngForTrackBy = this.trackBy.bind(this);
  }

  trackBy(index: number, item: T) {
    if (!this.propertyName) {
      throw new Error(`Property name not defined`);
    }
    if (typeof item[this.propertyName] === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error(`Property "${this.propertyName}" is undefined`);
    }
    const value = item[this.propertyName];
    console.log(
      `Item "${index}" trackByProp "${this.propertyName}" with value "${value}"`
    );
    return value;
  }

  @Input()
  set ngForTrackByProp(value: keyof T) {
    this.propertyName = value;
  }

  static ngTemplateContextGuard<T>(
    dir: NgForTrackByPropDirective<T>,
    ctx: any
  ): ctx is NgForTrackByPropDirective<T> {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ul *ngFor="let item of list; trackByProp: 'id'">
    <li>{{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  list = [
    { id: 0, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 1, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 2, name: 'baz' },
  ];
}
```

this the [ONLINE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbrtw1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The code works, but I want to make sure the property passed is a key of the item of the collection and in case it isn't, let the error be a compile error, eg.:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ul *ngFor="let item of list; trackByProp: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'">
    <li>{{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  list = [
    { id: 0, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 1, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 2, name: 'baz' },
  ];
}
```

side note, my *tsconfig.json*:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  "strictTemplates": true,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true
}
```

Comment: That would be cool. I also miss this with `let` projectors, but I think it is a missing feature in the Angular Language Server extension.

Comment: @Silvermind There is a directive for the let with strict type checking https://github.com/nigrosimone/ng-let

Comment: To get the obvious out of the way, you may want to [edit] your question to let people know if you've turned on the `strictTemplates` option in tsconfig.json.

Comment: @ar099968 I mean inside things like the Angular Material mat-table

Comment: @Silvermind see this example with another library of same guy https://github.com/nigrosimone/ng-as#example-mattable

Comment: Great idea! I have made a npm library https://github.com/nigrosimone/ng-for-track-by-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can narrow the type of an item in passing array by defining `ngForOf` `@Input` property:

```
import { NgIterable, ... } from '@angular/core';

...
export class NgForTrackByPropDirective<T> {

  @Input() ngForOf: NgIterable<T>;

  constructor(@Host() public ngForOfDir: NgForOf<T>) {
    this.ngForOfDir.ngForTrackBy = this.trackBy.bind(this);
  }
  ...
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ew463v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**